# qgis2compat can't be installed in Yakkety

Tags: qgis, linux, qfield

I want to use QField and Qfield sync. QField depends of qgis2compat and I can't install it.

I have QGIS 2.14.5 and Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety and can't install qgis2compat plugin because the lack of QtWebKit because python-qt4-webkit has been removed.

Is there a workaround?